# React Native - ios - circle with border - circle background color spilling out of circle

Tags: ios, css, react-native, geometry

I'm trying to create a circle with a white background in react native and i'm having an issue where the background color of the circle is seen on the outline of the border.

Check out this playground app:
https://rnplay.org/apps/TsQ-CA

If you look closely you can see that around the circle there's a thin black line. It's like the border isn't covering the entire background.

Here's the circle style:

`circle: {
    borderRadius: 40,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }`

P.S. this only happens on iOS

Any ideas??
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like a bug in React Native. You can work around it by using 2 circles:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.outerCircle}>
         <View style={styles.innerCircle} />
       </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  outerCircle: {
    borderRadius: 40,
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  innerCircle: {
    borderRadius: 35,
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
});
```

Comment: This does not draw anything on screen!

Comment: more like a hack.

Answer (score 25):

You can add different border color to a circle. try this

```
container: {
  width: 60,
  height: 60,
  borderRadius: 60 / 2,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  borderColor: 'black',
  borderWidth: 3
}
```

[image]

Comment: backgroundColor: 'red'

Answer (score 4):

Try setting style props as

```
{
overflow: 'hidden'
}
```

with your styling on View style.

Comment: this solved the problem in my case, without overflow hidden, backGround will tale all area including the borders

Comment: THIS. I'm making semicircles which work perfectly in Android, but iOS was adding length to the semicircle and making them look off. With this one line solution iOS can draw the semicircles. Thanks!